# showsMyLocationButton not working in android(react-native-maps)

Tags: react-native, google-maps

showsMyLocationButton not working in android

```
 <MapView
            style={styles.map}
            region={this.state.initalRegion}
            showsUserLocation={`enter code here`true}
            showsMyLocationButton={true}
    </MapView>
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code? Preferably in https://snack.expo.io/ And please share the full error log you get.

Comment: When screen rotate it will appear, hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <View
    style={[styles.container, {paddingTop: this.state.statusBarHeight}]}>
    <MapView
      onMapReady={() => {
          setTimeout(() => this.setState({statusBarHeight: 1}), 500);
          setTimeout(() => this.setState({statusBarHeight: 0}), 750);
      }}
```

This may work